# CSS Background Image Fade

Tags: css, background-image

Hi I'm trying to fade a background image when a certain part of the page is hovered on. Like a square div over a section of the page. Is that possible? The background image would be the size of the window and the square would be over it but not full sized.

Does anyone have a tutorial that shows this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried or researched something?

Comment: *Does anyone have a tutorial that shows this?* **Google will answer that**

Comment: Hi, always remember to Google first! A query for `CSS Background Image Fade` gives me plenty of results. Are they not helpful? If not, can you elaborate why?

Comment: @FDL I can make this with CSS alone

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS3 transitions this should work:

```
#div{
    background: url("yourimage");
  }

#div:hover{
    @include transition-property(background);
    @include transition-duration(0.5s);
    background: none;
  }
```

Above example is with SASS. If you are not using SASS, you will need to use more lines of code for cross-browser compatibility.

Reference: [CSS3 Transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You are not likely to find exact code so Here is the logic

1. Background property cannot be fade , so you need to use a div with background:url(imagepath.jpg),position:absolute,opacity:1 and width:100% and min-height:800 and so
2. On your second div hover you need to use jquery animate effect and set opacity to .5 ( or anything) of above div

this will help i guess